# which is the right prosite pattern?

Tags: sequence-alignment, prosite

I would like to ask if the right Prosite pattern for this multiple alignment:

[image]

Is it this:

```
A-T-[AT]-G-x-C-[AGC]-C-x(1,4)-A
```

or this:

```
A-T-[AT]-G-x-C-[AGC]-C-x(1,3)-[ATGC]-A
```

Actually, I would like to ask if `x` always implies a gap, and if it is proper to use it when any symbol but not gap can be in the sequence. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nucleotides are acceptable in prosite format because I thought it was protein motifs, the most accurate would be,

```
A-T-[AT]-G-x-C-[AGC]-C-[GCA](0,1,3)-x-A
```

The key point is that,

1. `[GCA](0,1,3)` of `x(0, 1, 3)` means zero/ nucleotides (3 indels) or one/ G or C or A nucleotide, and 2 indels or three/ G or C or A nucleotides.
2. `x` is any nucleotide i.e. A or G or T or C - it doesn't mean an indel. `x(0, 1)` is the best representation of a single indel (you call them gaps), here meaning any nucleotide may or may not be present at a given site.

Example from Prosite documentation:

> `<A-x-[ST](2)-x(0,1)-V`
>
> This pattern, which must be in the N-terminal
> of the sequence ('<'), is translated as:
>
> Ala-any-[Ser or Thr]-[Ser or Thr]-(any or none)-Val